# Enter twice in socket.on event

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and Node.js.
My code executes a socket.emit to a server side function and receives a response in the socket.on event ('listartists').
Unfortunately, he enters twice in this event and I do not understand why.
On the server side (app.js) I put logs and the function is called correctly once, but then it goes through the socket.on twice ('listartists').

Thank you all

```
var appAng = angular.module('appAng', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  socket.on('listartists', function(msg) {  
    // !!! enter twice this part of the code
    var ClientMessage = JSON.parse(msg);
    if (ClientMessage.ClientID == GetClientUniqueId()) {                
      var artistslist = JSON.parse(ClientMessage.Message);            
      $scope.$apply(function() {        
        var artistslist=JSON.parse(ClientMessage.Message);
        $scope.artists = artistslist;      
      }); 
    }   
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "enters twice"? You're also parsing `ClientMessage.Message` twice for some reason. Can you show your backend code? Assuming socket.io there's different [methods for broadcasting](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/).

Comment: Hi thanks for replay!The code inside the event socket.on() is not important. In fact, the problem is that it enters two times in the event. if I write the socket.on event out of the angular module then it executes it only once, but I have no way of using the scope outside

Answer (score 0):

i modified my code as :

```
socket.on('listartists', function(msg){  
var ClientMessage=JSON.parse(msg);
if (ClientMessage.ClientID== GetClientUniqueId())
{
    console.log("Arriva Lista Artisti " + ClientMessage.ClientID);
    var artistslist =JSON.parse(ClientMessage.Message);
    $scope.artists = artistslist; 
    $scope.$apply( function(){}); 

}
});
```

Anyway if i remove $scope.$apply( function(){});  the socket.on event is called only once,
otherwise it passes twice from there.
I think the problem is the management of the SCOPE some idea?